# Cannot insert into a column on context.saveChanges

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to update an entity using Entity Framework 4.1 in my asp.net MVC 3 application but I am getting some errors on columns which I am not updating.

I have few columns which are not null in db; I am not updating them. When I do `context.saveChanges`, I am getting an error that the column can't be null. How do I fix this?

Comment: How are you trying to update are you updating the whole entity object or you updating each instance of this object separately if you are updating the whole object then you will most likely get this error.

Comment: @COLDTOLD: I am updating like this:  internal void SaveAccount(Account account) {
            context.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

Comment: that why you getting this error you are modifying the whole state of the entity you either have to update each instance like account.id=id and so on or you have to assign values to null if you want to use modified and not get error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fix it by assigning values to fields that cannot be null.